# Does the skills boost percentage stack with 2 rings?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

There are rings that boosts skills, for example a Earth Shaker ring boosts ability by 30%. I assume this is 30% more damage. If I have 2 of these rings, does the boost stack?

Comment: From what I read, many of those rings are broken anyway and don't do anything. And they generally only increase durations, not damage

Comment: @MadScientist can you give me a link for what you said?

Comment: @Huangism I was wondering if rings stack too, and I found [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/dragonage/comments/2nw4q7/ability_rings_30_and_why_you_shouldnt_use_them/) about how the ability rings don't work (what Mad Scientist was mentioning I guess), but apparently whatever problem they had got fixed. Still though, I would be itnerested in getting an answer as to whether ability rings stack or not.

Comment: @DarthPizza That thread says this: "(LARGE BUG) - Stacking rings will often cancel the original effect (if it has not already been cancelled.) However, if the original bonus does apply, removing both rings can actually drop your base ability lower than it's original strength. The system only gives you the benefit of one ring in a best case scenario -130% dmg. Removing one ring drops it back to 100%, removing the second can drop it to 70%. Luckily, these changes are also cleared by moving to a new location, loading a new game, etc." But then an edit says everything works properly after patches

Answer (score 4):

It appears to depend on the type of ring.  By Earth Shaker I assume you mean [this](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Enhanced_Earthshaking_Strike_Ring)?  Assuming that all the bugs have been fixed (which they almost certainly aren't) and rings now function as they are supposed to I think a user from [this](https://forum.bioware.com/topic/525822-do-two-of-the-same-rings-stack/) thread says it best:

"Ability improvement rings work by **setting** an abilities properties to a 30% higher number all other rings **add** a bonus to stats. You can see this in the abilities tooltip the damage or duration number there changes on equip. Using 2 ability improvement rings has no use but 2 heal on kill rings for 10% each gives you 20% of your max HP with each kill and 2x20% crit damage gives +40%. This is the same in single and multiplayer."

I managed to find 2 instances [here](https://forum.bioware.com/topic/525822-do-two-of-the-same-rings-stack/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/DragonAgeCoOp/comments/2ohtkp/do_crit_chance_rings_stack/) where people had actually done methodical tests on stacking rings.  In both cases they found that stacking rings had no effect but equally there are plenty of people saying that they're sure stacking does work.

I would say that with the bugs and stacking (maybe) working with some rings and not others the only way to be sure would be to do a test yourself whenever you find yourself wanting to stack rings.  Equip them and see if anything changes on the tooltip or your attributes screen, then also maybe also do a damage test with 1 equipped and then with both.  My feeling is its probably not worth it.  Just use different rings.