# Do fade touched enchantments stack?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

Similar to [rings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/200854/does-the-skills-boost-percentage-stack-with-2-rings), I want to know if fade touched enchantments stack.

For example, I have a dagger that adds a 10% chance to use Hidden Blades on a hit, if I enchant another dagger with that ability, will that increase my chances of proccing hidden blades?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://forum.bioware.com/topic/527718-do-fade-touched-hidden-blades-stack/, each instance will be rolled seperately, meaning you will get two 10% chances, not one 20% chance.

Comment: Your answer isn't correct, but the correct answer is in your link, apparently items of the same 'tier' will not stack with each other but different tiers with the same ability will stack, but that's just from a forum source so I'm not sure how accurate it is still.